# How to align equations in different rows in a table at "=" with tabularray?

Tags: tabularray

I made a table that contains several equations which are located in different rows. I need to align them at `=` symbol. Such as this one:
[image]

My table is:
[image]

My code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx,amsmath}


\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
                  caption={test},
                  label={tab:test}
                  ]{
                    colsep=0.5pt,
                    colspec={c X[c,2.3] c
                                },rowhead=1
                  }
    \toprule
      one&two&{{{$\mathrm{R}^2$（three）}}} \\
    \midrule
      \SetCell[r=6]{c} 1  5+23&\SetCell[r=6]{c} {{{$\begin{aligned} [\ce{Ca^2+}]=&-3.19301 \mathrm{pH}^{3}\\&-5.11013 \mathrm{pH}^{2}\\&- 991.914 \mathrm{pH}\\&+10^{0.0420576 \mathrm{pH}+3.90459}\\&-7521.77\end{aligned}$}}}&\SetCell[r=6]{c} 0.996176\\
       & & \\
       & & \\
       & & \\
       & & \\
       & & \\
     \hline[dotted]
       \SetCell[r=5]{c} 2  5+23&\SetCell[r=5]{c} {{{$\begin{aligned} [\ce{HCO3-}]=&-0.540849 \mathrm{pH}^{3}\\&+12.9563\mathrm{pH}^{2}\\&- 103.195 \mathrm{pH}\\&+10^{ \mathrm{pH}-103.348}\\&+274.589\end{aligned}$}}}&\SetCell[r=5]{c} 0.996175\\
       & &  \\
       & & \\
       & & \\
       & & \\
    \bottomrule    
  \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This isn't really relevant to your question, but I'm curious why you're using U+FF08 and U+FF09 "fullwidth" parentheses around "（three）" rather than just "(three)". Made the code not compile the first time.

Comment: @frabjous Hello, thanks for your reply. I am Chinese, so I made this table for the first time in Chinese using U+FF08 and U+FF09. The time I asked the question here, I needed to wipe all Chinese characters but `（three)` is something I forgot to replace.

Answer (score 4):

Although I see the temptation to use an `aligned` environment, I think it's probably simpler, if you're already using a table, to let the table do the aligning; tables are good at that.

What I mean is introduce a column for the left side of the equations and a column for the right side, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx,amsmath}


\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}[
                  caption={test},
                  label={tab:test}
                  ]{
                    colsep=0.5pt,
                    colspec={c X[r,1] @{\ } X[l,1.5,$] c
                    },
                    rowhead=1
                  }
    \toprule
    one & \SetCell[c=2]{c} two & & $\mathrm{R}^2$ (three) \\
    \midrule
     \SetCell[r=5]{c,m}1  5+23 & [\ce{Ca^2+}] =   & -3.19301 \mathrm{pH}^{3} & \SetCell[r=5]{c,m}0.996176\\
                               &                  & -5.11013 \mathrm{pH}^{2} & \\
                               &                  & - 991.914 \mathrm{pH}    & \\
                               &                  & +10^{0.0420576 \mathrm{pH}+3.90459} & \\
                               &                  & -7521.77                 & \\
     \hline[dotted]
     \SetCell[r=5]{c,m} 2  5+23 & [\ce{HCO3-}] = & -0.540849 \mathrm{pH}^{3}  & \SetCell[r=5]{c,m}0.996175\\
                                  &                & +12.9563\mathrm{pH}^{2}    & \\
                                  &                & -103.195 \mathrm{pH}       & \\
                                  &                & +10^{ \mathrm{pH}-103.348} & \\
                                  &                & +274.589                   & \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image: table with equations]

IMHO the code is a lot more readable too.

Comment: Hello. Could you tell me what is the function of `@{\ }` and the `$` in `X[l,1.5,$]`?

Comment: From where did you know `\\` can insert the suited blanks between columns?

Comment: The `@{\ }` suppresses the usual spacing and inserts what's in the braces in between the columns instead, in this case, a normal space to match the one on the other side of the equals sign. This is long standing LaTeX colspec notation coming from the array package; see [its documentation](https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/required/tools/array.pdf), which tabularray borrows. The `$` is a tabularray-specific option that puts the column in question into math mode, see [its documentation](https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf), page 20.

Comment: Actually, I guess `@` predates the array package and is just part of the standard LaTeX tabular colspec notation. See [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#@_and_!_expressions) for further explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot！You help me so much.

Comment: Maybe accept this as the answer then?